# Duplicate files copied in APK protobuf.meta on Googlemap for business

Tags: android, google-maps

I follow the instruction here to implement the Googlemap for business (Option 2: Import the SDK as a library module):

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/android-get-started
When I try to run the app the it return me this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK protobuf.meta
    File1: /Users/name/.android/build-cache/f333e5a1ed5f958c1e7d100de7935a31efd81cd6/output/jars/classes.jar
    File2: /Users/name/Documents/name/project-name/googlemapssdkm4b_lib/build/intermediates/bundles/default/classes.jar
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: 'test-environment.gradle'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}

android {


    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false        // true by default
        checkAllWarnings false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
        quiet true                // false by default
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'org.intellij', module: 'annotations'
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }

    if (System.getenv("CIRCLECI") || System.getenv("CIRCLE") || System.getenv("CI")) {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM"))
        }
    }



    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../company_debug.keystore")
            storePassword "company"
            keyAlias "company"
            keyPassword "company"
        }

        integration {
            storeFile file("../company.keystore")
            storePassword "company"
            keyAlias "company"
            keyPassword "company"
        }

        staging {
            storeFile file("../company.keystore")
            storePassword "company"
            keyAlias "company"
            keyPassword "company"
        }


        release {
            storeFile rootProject.file('pizza.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASS")
            keyAlias System.getenv("ALIAS_NAME")
            keyPassword System.getenv("ALIAS_PASS")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            jniDebuggable false
            debuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            testProguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [providerSuffix: ".dev"]
        }

        integration {
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath = "integration_distribution_emails.txt"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "release_notes.txt"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.integration
            applicationIdSuffix ".integration"
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            jniDebuggable false
            debuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [providerSuffix: ".integration"]
        }

        staging {
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath = "staging_distribution_emails.txt"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "release_notes.txt"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            jniDebuggable false
            debuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'
            manifestPlaceholders = [providerSuffix: ".staging"]
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-release.cfg'

        }
    }

}


kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':apphelper')
    compile project(':customview')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:design:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:' + project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:" + project.ANDROID_ARCH_VERSION
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:" + project.ANDROID_ARCH_VERSION
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:" + project.ANDROID_ARCH_VERSION
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"

//    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:" + project.GMS_VERSION
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:" + project.GMS_VERSION

    compile( project(':googlemapssdkm4b_lib') ){
        exclude group:'com.google.guava'
    }

    //Auto Scroll ViewPager
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

}
```

I tried to put

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'protobuf.meta'
    }
```

and the error above is just gone but when app is running, it will crash at runtime by saying that it can't find **com.google.android.m4b.maps.MapFragment**

I use Android Architecture Components in my project which may contain Guava but I already exclude it from **googlemapssdkm4b_lib** and it still not working.

Have anyone here used Googlemap for business and face this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried 'merge' instead of 'pickFirst' ?
https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Comment: Maybe, worth filing an issue in the [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788712). Also, as a Premium plan customer, you are entitled to technical support from Google support team: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @Jutikorn? I am facing similar issues in google pay integration.